# How to prevent converting decimal to int while doing math in Python?

Tags: python, integer, decimal

How do I prevent converting a `Decimal` to an `int` while doing math (executing functions like `//` or `*`) in Python?

To get the input as a decimal number, I am using `Decimal` from the `decimal` module.

When I do

```
from decimal import Decimal

foo = Decimal(input())
```

And input `3.8`, it outputs `3.8`, which is right. However, when I add a mathematical function, like

`print (foo // 2)`

to my code, it outputs `1`, whereas it's supposed to output `1.4`.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening, as the program that I am making *depends* on decimals.

Comment: `//` is **integer** division so it will always return an integer.

Comment: You're using floor division... use a single forwardslash for division rather than floor division.

Comment: use `/` to division, .

Comment: @prashantrana Thanks... solved! However, please consider posting that as an answer, so that I can upvote and check-mark it.

Comment: Both are "actual" division, it's about floor division

Comment: @MichaelButscher pretty sure it returns a `Decimal`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use `//`, just use `/`. `//` is floor division. This divides and returns the integer value of the quotient. It dumps the digits after the decimal.